# Three.js - How to convert import methods into regular js files

Tags: import, three.js

On this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k2c5upfo/1/, extern modules are called using the import method. I don't use node on my project. I'd like to convert all these import files into regular javascript files. How can I built them without using node.js ?

```
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.2/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.2/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { EffectComposer } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.2/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js';
import { ShaderPass } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.2/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js';
import { RenderPass } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.2/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js';
import { ClearPass } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.2/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ClearPass.js';
import { MaskPass, ClearMaskPass } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.2/examples/jsm/postprocessing/MaskPass.js';
import { CopyShader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.2/examples/jsm/shaders/CopyShader.js';
```

For example, I was able to call 'OrbitControls.js' on a older version of three.js by simply add another file. Can I still use this method ? Thank you

**EDIT :**

I managed to convert my workflow using es6 modules. I've been wondering if there's a way to only import specific modules. My generated output file has the same weight with theses two different lines.

```
import {Scene, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer, CylinderBufferGeometry, MeshNormalMaterial, Mesh} from "../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js";

import * THREE from "../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js";
```

Is there a way to only have the part of code that I need in my final output ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using global scripts is actually deprecate since `r117`. At the end of the year, using ES6 modules is the only way of importing example files.

> I don't use node on my project.

Not sure I understand this sentence. The above fiddle is unrelated to `node.js`. You can import ES6 modules directly in HTML files as long as you put the import statements into script tags that look like so:

```html
<script type="module">
</script>
```

This approach is also used by the official examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes exactly, to make my script run locally I use type="module". But for example, I've scope issue calling a method inside my <script type="module">. Does it mean that all my script (for the whole website) must be written inside this tag and that all my libs will be externs ?

Comment: You can still include global scripts into your application (check out how `timeliner_gui` is imported in this [demo](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_animation_authoring)) but the scoping issue can only be resolved by having the code in a single script tag. Or you refactor some of your code into modules and import them in your `index.html`.